# oracle query with several filter conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a oracle query:

```
select * from table1,table2 where table1.id1 = table2.id2 and 
--filters
table1.col2 = 'value_11' and table2.col2 = 'value_21'
or
table1.col2 = 'value_12' and table2.col2 = 'value_22'
or
table1.col2 = 'value_13' and table2.col2 = 'value_23'
...
```

How to rewrite the query if the filter conditions run upto a 100? like `(value_11,value_21),(value_12,value_22)......(value_1100,value_2200)`

EDIT: original query is this:

```
select 
    cust_country.cust_login_id 
  , cust_country.user_login_id
  , cust_country.country_name
  , cust_email.email 
from ( select 
           APP_USER.USER_ID, customer.cust_login_id
         , user_credential.user_login_id, COUNTRY.COUNTRY_NAME 
       from 
           app_user
         , user_ci
         , contact_info
         , address
         , country
         , customer
         , user_credential 
       where APP_USER.USER_ID = USER_CI.USER_ID 
         and CONTACT_INFO.CI_ID=USER_CI.CI_ID
         and ADDRESS.ADDR_ID=CONTACT_INFO.CI_ID 
         and ADDRESS.COUNTRY_ID=COUNTRY.COUNTRY_ID 
         and APP_USER.CUST_ID=CUSTOMER.CUST_ID 
         and USER_CREDENTIAL.USER_ID=APP_USER.USER_ID
     ) cust_country,

     ( select 
           customer.cust_login_id, APP_USER.USER_ID
         , user_credential.user_login_id, ipty_email.email
       from 
         app_user,user_ci,contact_info,ipty_email,customer,user_credential 
       where APP_USER.USER_ID = USER_CI.USER_ID 
         and CONTACT_INFO.CI_ID=USER_CI.CI_ID 
         and ipty_email.ipe_ID=CONTACT_INFO.CI_ID 
         and APP_USER.CUST_ID=CUSTOMER.CUST_ID 
         and USER_CREDENTIAL.USER_ID=APP_USER.USER_ID
     ) cust_email

where cust_country.user_id = cust_email.user_id 
  and (cust_country.cust_login_id, cust_country.user_login_id) in 
      (('xxxxyyyyy','ADMIN2'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could compress it (a bit) with:

```
SELECT *                                       --- irrelevant to the question:
FROM table1 JOIN table2                        --- use the explicit JOIN syntax
             ON table1.id1 = table2.id2        --- not the implicit join with the
---table1,table2 where table1.id1 = table2.id2 --- WHERE syntax (removed)
WHERE
--- filters
  AND (table1.col2, table2.col2) IN
        (  ('value_11', 'value_21'),
           ('value_12', 'value_22'),
           ('value_13', 'value_23'),
           ...
           (value_1100, value_2200)
        )
```

If you have these filter conditions in a table, you can even make it:

```
  AND (table1.col2, table2.col2) IN
        (  SELECT filter1, filter2
           FROM filter_table
        )
```

Comment: Thanks. When i try it, i get 'Invalid relational operator' at this line : (  ('value_11', 'value_21'),

Comment: @Kaushik: Which version or Oracle do you use?

Comment: It should work: [Oracle 10g, IN syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions013.htm#i1050801). You probably have misplaced a comma or a parenthesis. Can you provide the exact query you used?

Comment: Thanks. Can you see the query with only 1 set of filter value in my EDIT?

Comment: With only one filter, you should use: `in  (('xxxxyyyyy','ADMIN2'))`.

Comment: It works in versions 10g2 and later. Not sure about previous Oracle versions.

Comment: Ok man...I think I will accept the answer for now... i appreciate your time.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10985/discussion-between-ypercube-and-kaushik)

Comment: What exact version of Oracle do you use? Perhaps it is earlier than 10.2 ?