# Filtering more than one column in the same db

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two separate queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)employees FROM company
WHERE status = 'A' AND salary_rate IS NOT NULL;

SELECT COUNT(*)employees FROM company
WHERE status = 'A' AND current_level IS NOT NULL;
```

I want to show the results of these two queries in one query. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [oracle query with several filter conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457211/oracle-query-with-several-filter-conditions)

Comment: The above referenced link doesn't provide and answer

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:
[How to get multiple counts with one SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789396/how-to-get-multiple-counts-with-one-sql-query)

With that in mind, you want something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalcount, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN salary_rate IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt1,
   SUM(CASE WHEN current_level IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt2
FROM company
WHERE status = 'A';
```

Output will be the count of all records where status='A' and then counts of the two different 'not null' conditions (as cnt1 and cnt2).